# Create an alarm from DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: android

i want to create an alarm that notifies on the time set in  DatePicker and a TimePicker

My code is:

```
//Create alarm
                        GregorianCalendar tmpDate=new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),datePicker.getMonth(),datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                        long date=tmpDate.getTimeInMillis();
                        long hour=timePicker.getDrawingTime();
                        long dateTime=date+hour;
                        calendar=new GregorianCalendar();

                        if(dateTime<calendar.getTimeInMillis()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No puedes crear la alarma antes de hoy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            return;
                        }

AlarmManager alm=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime,mAlarmSender);
```

If i try adding 5 seconds to the current time works, but setting the time frim date and time picker don't notify.

Answer (score 0):

`timePicker.getDrawingTime()` doesn't return the time that is set in the timePicker. To retrieve the set time you need to use a `onTimeSetListener()` (see also [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html))

To check if you've done everything else correctly, you can log the dates you've got before setting the alarm like this:

```
Log.d("test", "Current time is "+new Date().toLocaleString();
Log.d("test", "Date is "+new Date(dateTime).toLocaleString();
```